# PySpark read GBK HDFS contain Chinese characters

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, text-files, gbk

I have many big HDFS files encoded in GBK, but these files contain special characters including Chinese etc. These Chinese strings would be shown or saved into a file. How can I handle the problem?

PySpark supports UTF-8 reader only.

- Spark version: 2.0.0.
- Hadoop version:2.7
- Python 2.7

Added as follows:

The result will be saved into file, then the result file will be used in another system, SDK for example. I printed one word, just like u'\ufffd\u0439\ufffd', which is obviously invalid.

Comment: You want to remove the or you want to display them? You can display them as Unicode characters if you want. something like this: `u'\u8bf7\u8f93'`

Comment: The result will be saved into file, then the result file will be used in another system,  SDK for example. I printed one word, just like u'\ufffd\u0439\ufffd', which is obviously invalid.

Comment: Problem solved as follow: create a temporary hive table encoded utf-8.

Comment: Same problem here, could you share the solution with more details?@MartinGau